# PHP парсинг JSON

Tags: php, json

Есть JSON, который тянется с https://zkillboard.com/api/kills/corporationID/1000107/limit/10/
Сам JSON не бросаю - он огромный
никак не могу его распарсить.

```
$jsons = file_get_contents('kills.json'); /* сохранил файлик с JSON и подгружаю */
$allkils = json_decode($jsons, true);
   var_dump ($allkils);
echo $allkils[1]['damage_taken'];
```

не работает
как получить доступ, если здесь 10 одинаковых JSON, но без номерации и пр.?
  var_dump выдает

```
array(10) { [0]=> array(6) { ["killmail_id"]=> int(68976609) ["killmail_time"]=> string(20) "2018-03-27T23:31:47Z" ["victim"]=> array(6) { ["damage_taken"]=> int(418) ["ship_type_id"]=> int(670) ["character_id"]=> int(2113841465) ["corporation_id"]=> int(98537886) ["items"]=> array(0) { } ["position"]=> array(3) { ["x"]=> float(-657873720135.67) ["y"]=> float(-238676064.43072) ["z"]=> float(222420445726.4) } } ["attackers"]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(8) { ["security_status"]=> float(4.7) ["final_blow"]=> bool(true) ["damage_done"]=> int(418) ["character_id"]=> int(2112031890) ["corporation_id"]=> int(98330748) ["alliance_id"]=> int(99006319) ["ship_type_id"]=> int(33468) ["weapon_type_id"]=> int(2456) } [1]=> array(8) { ["security_status"]=> float(1.4) ["final_blow"]=> bool(false) ["damage_done"]=> int(0) ["character_id"]=> int(2112189738) ["corporation_id"]=> int(98330748) ["alliance_id"]=> int(99006319) ["ship_type_id"]=> int(29986) ["weapon_type_id"]=> int(527) } [2]=> array(8) { ["security_status"]=> float(-0.6) ["final_blow"]=> bool(false) ["damage_done"]=> int(0) ["character_id"]=> int(91138520) ["corporation_id"]=> int(98330748) ["alliance_id"]=> int(99006319) ["ship_type_id"]=> int(22456) ["weapon_type_id"]=> int(5443) } } ["solar_system_id"]=> int(31000584) ["zkb"]=> array(8) { ["locationID"]=> int(40381505) ["hash"]=> string(40) "6b5a3a48f6f38738ec976e7c793aa9f2980faf61" ["fittedValue"]=> int(10000) ["totalValue"]=> int(10000) ["points"]=> int(1) ["npc"]=> bool(false) ["solo"]=> bool(false) ["awox"]=> bool(false) } } [1]=> array(6) { ["killmail_id"]=> int(68976595) ["killmail_time"]=> string(20) "2018-03-27T23:30:23Z" ["victim"]=> array(6) { ["damage_taken"]=> int(982) ["ship_type_id"]=> int(607) ["character_id"]=> int(2113841465) ["corporation_id"]=> int(98537886) ["items"]=> array(12) { [0]=> array(4) { ["item_type_id"]=> int(18635) ["singleton"]=> int(0) ["flag"]=> int(27) ["quantity_destroyed"]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(4) { ["item_type_id"]=> int(1405) ["singleton"]=> int(0) ["flag"]=> int(12) ["quantity_dropped"]=> int(1) } [2]=> array(4) { ["item_type_id"]=> int(33180) ["singleton"]=> int(0) ["flag"]=> int(20) ["quantity_destroyed"]=> int(1) } [3]=> array(4) { ["item_type_id"]=> int(30013) ["singleton"]=> int(0) ["flag"]=> int(5) ["quantity_dropped"]=> int(16) } [4]=> array(4) { ["item_type_id"]=> int(31213) ["singleton"]=> int(0) ["flag"]=> int(93) ["quantity_destroyed"]=> int(1) } [5]=> array(4)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

echo $allkils[0]['killmail_id']; дало результат!

Comment: И под вопросом и под ответом есть кнопка "правка". Внесите изменения вместо комментария.

Comment: @0xdb Уважаемый, я дал ответ на свой же вопрос, так как самостоятельно нашел проблему и устранил. это НЕ возбраняется правилами сайта. второй коментарий под ответом лишний, тут я согласен

Comment: Нет, не возбраняется.  А что было в комментариях? Через две недели я уже не помню, что тут было.

Comment: да дубляж  ответа. только с парсингом большей глубины